# how can i use the pagination for hash data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `will_paginate gem` for pagination

here is **my code:**

```
allrecord2 = (w_post+w_like+w_shares).sort{|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }    

@wallpostrecord=allrecord2.sort{|a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }.group_by{|hase| hase.Pid}

@paginateData=@wallpostrecord.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using `to_a` for converting hash data to array .

Include this line in top of the controller : `require 'will_paginate/array'`

```
@paginateData=@wallpostrecord.to_a.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 25)
```